# Figure sequence

Tags: pattern, sequence

I have no clue how to solve this figure sequence. I do not see a pattern in the outer and inner figure.

[image]

Comment: Where did you find this puzzle?

Comment: I found this in an IQ-test.

Comment: If you found it from another source, please include a link of that website or something :) @user3757341

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I posit that the answer

> ... is B.
>
>  A is a repeat, as are D, and E. C's central is both new, and not a line construction.
>
>  B uses figures we've seen before, as well as not repeating an earlier figure.